# LinkedIn Oauth2 throws exception using Scribejava

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

This is the code from the tutorial [Getting Started](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/wiki/Getting-Started) and I'm only trying it, nothing else is running.

```
 public class Launch {

private static final String url =
    "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url)";
private static final String url2 =
        "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name)";

public Launch() {
    OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
            .provider(LinkedInApi.class)
            .apiKey("xxxx")
            .apiSecret("xxxx")
            .build();
    Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();

    String authUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
    Verifier v = new Verifier("verifier you got from the user");
    Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, v); // the requestToken you had from step 2
    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, url2);
    service.signRequest(accessToken, request); // the access token from step 4
    Response response = request.send();
    System.out.println(response.getBody());
}
```

In my **controller** I have:

```
@View
public Response.Content index(){
Launch launch = new Launch();
return index.ok();}
```

and when I try to launch it, it gives me this error:

> org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'oauth_problem=permission_unknown'

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: changed the code to add `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);` after the `ServiceBuilder` declaration to use it in `Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());`

And also, put manually the url found in the terminal which is the result of `System.out.println(service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken));`

It's a temporary url, but the only way this works till now.